# SimpleAuthentication - Storing User Specific Information To Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I walked through a couple of tutorials and it seems they all leave out how you can utilize the logged in user to store information to a database.  To help me illustrate my point, here is a model I've been using.

```
public class Note
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This each user can write a note to the database.  When I created the CRUD controller for this model I then updated the **UserId** property to the **WebSecurity.CurrentUserId** when doing Update/Create. Then when retrieving data back I filter the notes using Where in the linq expression.  For some reason this just feels wrong.

Trolling through even more examples I came across someone doing it like so.

```
public class Note
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; } 
        public string Text { get; set; }
}
public class NoteDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

This looks a lot cleaner since the models are properly linked in C#.  And wow, it actually builds!  So now in my controller I will first get the user object from the database, then using a Where list their notes.

```
//First get the logged in user
var user = dbUser.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserId == WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).First();
//Now get all their notes
var notes = db.Notes.Where(x => x.User == user);
```

[image: Failure Message]

However, this unexpectedly fails. So could someone please provide a sample of a good way to store the UserProfile object against other objects in the database? Basically, I just need a good example that shows now the UserProfile object can be linked to a Note object, and how you should properly query for Notes of a specific UserId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've defined your relationship, is that you are creating a one-to-one relationship between a `Note` and a `User`.  I would expect that a user can have multiple notes, based on the query that you're having trouble with. Thus, in order to create a one-to-many between a user and their notes, you should create a collection on your `UserProfile` object.  For instance,

```
public class UserProfile
{
   ...
   public List<Note> Notes {get; set;}
}
```

...and to query, loading your `Notes` associated with that user,

```
var user = myUsers.Include(n=>n.Notes)
                  .Single(x => x.UserId == WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear in saying, but the Note is stored on the Notes table using the code first entity stuff.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you mind showing how the CRUD controller would work? That would help

Answer (score 0):

Each user can have many notes, right? If so, change your class like this:

```
public class Note
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, have users and notes connecting correctly. So, you can easily achive your goal like the following. You also don't need to struggle with `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity` to get the current user! just use `User.Identity.Name` :

```
// ...
var notes = db.Notes.Where(x => x.User.UserName == User.Identity.Name).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Do you mind showing how the CRUD controller would work? That would help.

Comment: Also, I don't think User.Identity.Name is a primary key, as you can have more users with the same User.Identity.Name.